# Creating an alias (i.e. second name) for a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, redirect, routes

I have a production Rails 2.3.5 website, and I'd like to the change the name of a model to something that will look much better in the URLs.  I know the easy way to do this is in routes.rb like this:

```
map.resources :announcements, :as => :posts
```

However, I need to support the old name as well since we're production and can't have dead links.  Just using ':as' isn't going to cut it.

I'm basically looking for a way to redirect so that:

```
http://mysite.com/announcements/23
```

redirects to

```
http://mysite.com/posts/23
```

It's probably possible to do this through Apache, but I can't seem to figure out the rewrite rules.  I thought maybe routes.rb would be an easier method.  Not having luck there either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution that works out pretty well.

I added the `:as => :posts` to my routes.rb, which makes all the link helpers create links to the new URLs.  Then I figured out a mod_rewrite rule to handle redirects so there aren't any broken links out there on the internets.  Here's what I added to my Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^/announcements(.*) /posts$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what we mean by "redirect" - it sounds like the most efficient route might be to take your posts controller and add redirects to announcements, and let the announcements controller handle the pages. So, in `PostsController`:

```
def index
  redirect_to 'announcements#index'
end
```

and so forth. That gives you legacy support for old links for as long as you want it, and if there ever comes a time that you don't want it anymore you can just drop the whole Posts Controller.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I ended up figuring out a simple mod_rewrite rule which I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the route two times. With `:as` option and without?

```
//routes.rb
map.resources :announcements
map.resources :announcements, :as => :posts
```